# Prototype select element with id that contains specific character

Tags: customer-address, prototype-js

I have a select box in admin customer address form like this:

```
<select id="_item13country_id" name="address[13][country_id]" class="required-entry countries required-entry select required-entry select">
 <option value=""> </option>
 <option value="TH" selected="selected">Thailand</option>
</select>
```

I need to select country field by using prototype to find which element that contains

> country_id

How can I do that ?. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select element with id "country_id"

```
$$("[id*=country_id]")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$$('$=country_id')` to get the elements that have the id ending with `country_id` and `$$('$=country_id')[0]` to get the first of these elements.

or use `$$('[id*=country_id]')` to select the elements that contain the text `country_id` in the id attribute.
Again, to select the first element use `$$('[id*=country_id]')[0]`